# How to check if a bone layer is empty with python

Tags: python, scripting, armature

[image]

When I run my script, I want to activate only the bone layer that contains bones and mute the empty layers without bones.
Is there an api that can tell if a layer is empty or not?

Answer (score 0):

The layer data in an armature is just a list of bools, so you can't check if it has any bones like that. My solution was to loop through every layer, then check if there were any bones assigned to that layer.

```
    def check_layer_data(self, layer, context):
        for bone in context.object.data.bones:
            if bone.layers[layer]:
                return True

        return False
```

There might be a better way to do this considering I'm not the best programmer, but this worked for me.